# Using ng-pattern with angular and bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web development. Now My code is like this ->

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
                    <div ng-show="errorMessage" class="compact-container alert text-center alert-danger col-xs-12"> {{errorMessage}}</div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/" data-ng-model="formInfo.username"
                            value="" placeholder="username or email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.pattern">
                        <span class="jdIdError-Color">Please use Lower case charchters</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="formInfo.password" name="password" required
                            placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->

                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info login-button-position" id="loginBtn" name="loginBtn" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid"
                                data-ng-click="isLoading=true;submit(loginForm)">
                                    <span ng-hide="hideSpinner"
                                       class="loginContainer-spinner">
                                     <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
                                   </span>
                                <span class="text-white"><strong>Login</strong></span>
                            </button>
                            <!--<a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="isLoading=true;submit(loginForm)">Login </a>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

SO, when I give the error message it is giving like this

[image]

Here I have removed the div and now when I tried to take that message a bit up using margin then it is not happening. so,

[image]

Comment: remove error div from form group class

Comment: Hey, thanks for this I did that , Please check my updated question

Comment: I want to have that message in that div only because user will come to know easily .

Comment: <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">

Comment: remove the bottom margin

Answer (score 0):

Move the error div out of the input-group div:

```
 <form name="loginForm" id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
  <div ng-show="errorMessage" class="compact-container alert text-center alert-danger col-xs-12"> {{errorMessage}}</div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/" data-ng-model="formInfo.username" value="" placeholder="username or email" required>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.pattern">
    <span class="jdIdError-Color">Please use Lower case charchters</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove error div from input group class

```html
<form name="loginForm" id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    <div ng-show="errorMessage" class="compact-container alert text-center alert-danger col-xs-12"> {{errorMessage}}</div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/" data-ng-model="formInfo.username"
        value="" placeholder="username or email" required>
        
    </div>
    <div ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.pattern">
       <span class="jdIdError-Color">Please use Lower case charchters</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provide "help-block" class for validation error.
So you need to wrap 'input-group' into form group add add class "help-block" to your span

Please see example below

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script> ​
<div class="container">
  <form name="loginForm" id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    ​
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                </span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/" data-ng-model="formInfo.username" value="" placeholder="username or email" required>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.pattern">
        <span class="jdIdError-Color help-block">Please use Lower case charchters</span>
      </div>
      ​
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                </span>
        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="formInfo.password" name="password" required placeholder="password">
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
        <!-- Button -->
        ​
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info login-button-position" id="loginBtn" name="loginBtn" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid" data-ng-click="isLoading=true;submit(loginForm)">
                        <span ng-hide="hideSpinner" class="loginContainer-spinner">
                            <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="text-white">
                            <strong>Login</strong>
                        </span>
                    </button>
          <!--<a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="isLoading=true;submit(loginForm)">Login </a>-->
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```